# How to handle Fetch api formData submit using expressJS

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

So i am trying to submit fetch api post request and  formData into a API that was made using `expressJS` but it returns undefined after submitting, but when i tried to use postman it received the data successfully. I want to replicate the scenario in postman using fetch api, below is my code.

Fetch API

```
submit.addEventListener('click', ()=> {

    let formData = new FormData();
    let fname = document.querySelector('#fname').value;
    let lname = document.querySelector('#lname').value;
    let email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
    let gender = document.querySelector('#gender').value;

    formData.append('fname', fname);
    formData.append('lname', lname);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('gender', gender);

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/members',  {

        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          }
      });


});
```

My ExpressJS API code

```
app.use(cors()); // installed cors just incase
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

 app.post('/api/members', (req, res)=> {
      var fname = req.body.fname;
      var lname = req.body.lname;
      var email = req.body.email;
      var gender = req.body.gender;

      console.log(req.body) // i added a consolelog to show body

      connection
      .query(`INSERT INTO userdata (first_name, last_name, email, gender)VALUES('${fname}','${lname}','${email}','${gender}')`,(err, rows, fields) => {
        if(err) throw err
        res.json({msg: `1 rows was inserted`});
      });
 });
```

My postman settings are POST->BODY->x-www-form-urlencoded

> Edit

I included an console.log(req.body) on express to show the what it gets and the output is below.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  '-----------------------------47133174525661\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"fname"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'dau\r\n' +
    '-----------------------------47133174525661\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lname"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'duiasd\r\n' +
    '-----------------------------47133174525661\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'test@email.com\r\n' +
    '-----------------------------47133174525661\r\n' +
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    'Female\r\n' +
    '-----------------------------47133174525661--\r\n'
}
```

Comment: Have you enable CORS in your express app? If not, you can use a third-party package. `npm i cors` `app.use(cors())`

Comment: Yes cors is enabled on express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this code below:

**‍ In Your Fetch API:**

```js
submit.addEventListener('click', ()=> {

  let fname = document.querySelector('#fname').value;
  let lname = document.querySelector('#lname').value;
  let email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
  let gender = document.querySelector('#gender').value;

  let formData = { fname, lname, email, gender };

  fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/members',  {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    });
});
```

You can read the documentation [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Now, you can `console.log()` it first.

```js
app.post('/api/members', (req, res)=> {
  console.log(req.body);
  // do some stuff here
});
```

I hope it's can help .

Comment: It work! Thanks i just don't understand why instead if application/x-www-form-urlencode it has to use application/json instead, any thanks again.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question thou.  It's asking for FormData submission not json data.

Comment: @FabricioG for new developer, sometimes they are doesn't know how to ask some question from their case. So, how to know the right answer, just give the answer to solve their problem, not find what's right or whats wrong.